# Transit Visa at Manchester Airport

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, transit-visas, norway

I am an Indian citizen and I have a long term EEA residence permit. I will be traveling from Norway to India with transit in Manchester. Unfortunately, I have to check-in again at Manchester as the airlines are different (SAS and Thomas Cook airlines). Will I need a transit visa?

Comment: Yes you will need a visa for this.

Comment: You may need more than a visa if you’re flying with Thomas Cook https://www.dailyrecord.co.uk/news/business-consumer/thomas-cook-bailout-calls-tories-20139182